Why the already set value is being reset to the new value in the for loop condition in C?
I am studying for my programming course and one of the questions on the last test has this code that has to be "calculated".
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    short a[4] = {66, 066, 0x66};
    int i = 0, s = 0, p = 15;

    for (++a[i]; !i, p = a[i]; s += a[i++]) {
        p = a[i] >> 2 | p;
        a[i] &= p;
    }

    printf("%d", s);
}

The original question is to find the value of s, but I have a problem understanding why p = 67 is' before the first iteration' if it was declared as p = 15. Isn't p = a[i] the loop condition and not a way to declare a value?
I tried "calculating" for p = 15 where I didn't get the right result and for p = 67 where I did get the right result.

!i, p = a[i]; does not do what you imagine. The first condition is ignored, and the second part sets p to a[i]; and tests its value.

"why is p = 67 before first iteration?" ++a[i] sets a[0] to 67. Then p = a[i] sets p to 67.

The middle part of the for loop needs to be evaluated to decide if the loop should be entered. If that has side effects then they would happen before the first iteration, even if the result was false and the loop wasn't entered.

Does this answer your question? What does the comma operator , do?

@phuclv While I did find learning more about , operator usefull, I already new some of that stuff. The answers that helped me the most were the first comment of Wether Vane and both answers from John Bayko and Lundin. I am not sure how I can thank them since It's my first time using stack overflow, but those answers were specific, short and understandable.

I understand this is deliberately badly written for a test, but I hope you realise how bad it is and why it shouldn't be that way. Deconstructing it might help clarify what it's actually doing.
First, it has too many side effects, and too many actions unrelated to the control of the loop. It'll help to convert the for loop into a while, so this:
    for (++a[i]; !i, p = a[i]; s += a[i++]) {
        ...
    }

Becomes this:
    ++a[i];
    while (!i, p = a[i]) {
        ...
        s += a[i++];
    }

The , operator performs two operations, but only returns the results of the second. It can be useful if you want side effects of the first operation that affect the second one, but !i has no side effects, so can be discarded. So the loop is now:
    ++a[i];
    while (p = a[i]) {
        ...
        s += a[i++];
    }

The test expression is an assignment, which can be confusing at first glance, so isn't a good idea. Assignments shouldn't be in conditional expressions. It can be moved out, and replaced by the assigned variable p, but p is updated in two places, on just before the loop, and one just before the end of the loop.
    ++a[i];
    p = a[i];  // Update p here first.
    while (p) {
        ...
        s += a[i++];
        p = a[i];  // Update p before looping again.
    }

That should make the loop clear. Inside, p is in an expression on both sides of the = sign, While this is allowed, it means one variable is used for two things, and you need to switch your thinking when that happens - if you miss it, you'll be thinking of the wrong meaning for the variable. Add a new variable every time the meaning changes:
    short a[4] = {66, 066, 0x66};
    int i = 0, s = 0, p = 15;

    ++a[i];
    p = a[i];
    while (p) {
        int m = a[i] >> 2 | p;
        a[i] &= m;
        s += a[i++];
        p = a[i];
    }

It should be clear that p can be replaced by a[i] everywhere it's used, but I'll leave it as it is. That should make it clear exactly what the code does now, and why. You can convert the while loop back into a for loop if you want:
    for (p = a[i];p;p = a[i]) {

It doesn't exactly seem useful, but that's what it ends up being, so I'd leave it as a while loop.

What you have in the test condition of the for loop is the comma command.
In the comma command you can do several operations separated by a comma and the last operation is what is going to be returned to the calling context.
e.g.
int x = (1,2,a[i]=4);

In this case 1 and 2 are just ignored and 4 will both be assigned to a[I] and returned to be assigned to x.
Have a look at this explanation.

Needless to say, this is "obfuscated" code: code deliberately written in bad ways to confuse the reader.

++a[i] This grabs the contents of a[0] and increases it by 1. a[0] is now 67. Since it is the first for loop clause it only gets executed once, before the loop starts.
!i, ... this is a "no-op"; it does nothing. The left operand of the comma operator is evaluated first, but the value returned is that of the right operand, p = a[i] in this case. p becomes 67 or if you will 0x43. The loop will break when a[i] is zero.
a[i] >> 2 right shift by 2, which is also the same as divide by 2, 2 times. Note that << has higher precedence than |. 0x43 >> 2 gives 0x10
0x10 | 0x42 gives 0x53.
 a[i] &= p; is 0x43 & 0x53 which gives us the value 0x43 back again.
Round it goes, doing bitwise nonsense on the other values in the array too, then restoring their original values.
s += a[i++] just sums the values of the array and then increases i by 1.
Since there was an array of 4 values but the last one was not initialized explicitly by the programmer, it was initialized implicitly to zero. So the loop breaks on the 4th value when i==3.

So all the code is good for in practice is to increase the first array item value by 1, then sum:
66+1 (dec) + 066 (octal) + 0x66 (hex) = 223

To understand code like this, it might be helpful to add a whole lot of print statements:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    short a[4] = {66, 066, 0x66};
    int i = 0, s = 0, p = 15;

    for (++a[i]; printf("i:%d ",i), !i, p = a[i]; printf("s:%d \n", s += a[i++])) {
        printf("p:%.2X ", p);
        p = a[i] >> 2 | p;
        printf("p:%.2X ", p);
        a[i] &= p;
        printf("a[%d]:%.2X ", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\ns:%d", s);
}

Output:
i:0 p:43 p:53 a[0]:43 s:67 
i:1 p:36 p:3F a[1]:36 s:121 
i:2 p:66 p:7F a[2]:66 s:223 
i:3 

s:223

Or better yet just single-step through the code in your debugger and watch all variable values.
